# Inserting SQL DATA into VB Database

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Sorry for the NOOB question I just started with VB. I finally managed to connect my program with my phpmyadmin account, but now I have this little problem.

I am trying to enter the Data the user entered into the form into the db table. 
My syntax is wrong. Im doing the following:

```
Dim SQLStatment As String = "INSERT INTO students(Title, Initial, Surname, Address, City, Country, Postcode) VALUES('" & vtital & vinital & surname & vstreet & vcity & vcountry & vpcode '")"
```

If anyone could be so kind to give me a brief explanation on how to enter multiple variable data into a db using vb.net it would be much appreciated.

Comment: avoid concatenate in sql command .. use parameterized one .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the separator

It should be like this ..

```
Dim SQLStatment As String = "INSERT INTO students(Title, Initial, Surname, Address, City, Country, Postcode) VALUES('" & vtital & "','" & vinital & "','" & surname & "','" & vstreet & "','" & vcity & "','" & vcountry & "','" & vpcode & "')"
```

Later .. use parameterized..

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it is giving me the error 'operator & is not defined for types string and windows.forms.textboxes. What am I missing here?

Comment: same error :-( Im obviously doing something wrong, the data is made up of both integer and string types, which is received from text boxes. Perhaps my DIM declaration is wrong?

Comment: @Marilee .. is `vtital` a textbox name ? or string variable ?

Comment: it is a variable of type string

Comment: @Marilee .. if you did `dim vtital as string = textbox1.text` and so on for another variable, your code should work ..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Dim SQLStatment As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO students(Title, Initial, Surname, Address, City, Country, Postcode) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",
vtital, 
vinital,
surname,
vstreet,
vcity,
vcountry,
vpcode)
```